# Creating a basic java Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a plain GUI just to practice and get the hang of it, and the one I created compiles fine. But there isn't any output that I can observe apart from it just saying 'build successful'.
I've only created a `JButton` button and a `JTextField` text field that is supposed to display a value when you press the button but it doesn't seem to do that.

```
package swing;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 1stef
 */
public class Swing implements ActionListener {
    
        private Frame f;
        private Button b;
        private TextField w1;
        private Panel p;
        private MenuBar mb;
        private Menu M;
        private MenuItem miR;
        
                
        
        public Swing(){
            
        f=new Frame("TEst");
        b= new Button("Display hello");
        w1=new TextField();
        p =new Panel();
        mb =new MenuBar();
        M=new Menu("Hello");
        miR = new MenuItem("Option");
        }
        
        public void setGUI(){
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        p.add(w1);
        p.add(b);
        mb.setHelpMenu(M);
        f.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        b.addActionListener(this);
        }
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Display hello")){
        w1.setText("This si how we wash our clothes");
        
        }
        }
            
        
        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Swing().setGUI();
               
       
    }
```

Comment: You created a frame with some controls, but you forgot to make the frame visible by calling `f.setVisible(true);`

Comment: You're using AWT, not Swing.  Swing components start with the letter J (JFrame, JButton, etc.).  Follow the Oracle tutorial, Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing, to properly learn Swing.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Answer (score 1):

use this solution, you have to show the frame using `f.show()` or you can use `f.setVisible(true);` instead of `.show()`

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 1stef
 */
public class Swing implements ActionListener {
    
        private Frame f;
        private Button b;
        private TextField w1;
        private Panel p;
        private MenuBar mb;
        private Menu M;
        private MenuItem miR;
        
                
        
        public Swing(){
            
        f=new Frame("TEst");
        b= new Button("Display hello");
        w1=new TextField();
        p =new Panel();
        mb =new MenuBar();
        M=new Menu("Hello");
        miR = new MenuItem("Option");
        }
        
        public void setGUI(){
            f.setSize(400,400);
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        p.add(w1);
        p.add(b);
        mb.setHelpMenu(M);
        f.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        b.addActionListener(this);
        f.show();
        }
        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Display hello")){
        w1.setText("This si how we wash our clothes");
        
        }
        }
            
        
        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new Swing().setGUI();
               
       
    }
}
```

output of your program like below though your UI design is not good[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your not showing anything. To fix this you need to add `f.setVisible(true);` to the end of `setGUI`. You should also add `f.pack();` to it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/**
*
* @author 1stef
*/
public class Swing implements ActionListener {

private Frame f;
private Button b;
private TextField w1;
private Panel p;
private MenuBar mb;
private Menu M;
private MenuItem miR;

public Swing(){

    f=new Frame("TEst");
    b= new Button("Display hello");
    w1=new TextField();
    p =new Panel();
    mb =new MenuBar();
    M=new Menu("Hello");
    miR = new MenuItem("Option");
}

public void setGUI(){
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    p.add(w1);
    p.add(b);
    mb.setHelpMenu(M);
    f.add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    b.addActionListener(this);
    
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Display hello")){
        w1.setText("This si how we wash our clothes");
    }
}


/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Swing().setGUI();
}
}
```